# R lidR catalog_retile returns clipped output

Tags: r, lidr

I am trying to stich a few `LAS` `tiles` into a `single` file. The final retiled LAS appears to be clipped.

How can I fix the clipping issue?

LAS list catalog plot:

[image]

Code:

```
library(lidR)

# Create a LAS catalog object
LAS_List = readLAScatalog("path")

# Merge LAS files into a single LAS file
opt_chunk_buffer(LAS_List ) = 0
opt_chunk_size(LAS_List ) = 10000
opt_output_files(LAS_List ) = paste0("path2/Final_LAS")
catalog_retile(LAS_List )

# Plot the merged LAS
Final_LAS = readLAScatalog("path2")

plot(Final_LAS , mapview = TRUE,
     map.type = "OpenStreetMap")
```

Retile output:

[image]

Pattern of chunks (chunk size = 500):

[image]

Comment: Using a chunk size `1000000` fixes the problem, it does however a bigger tile including areas outside the input tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know. Here is a guess that you will be able to validate. You put 10000 for chunk size. But the alignment of the chunks may have created two chunks. You did not provided any template in the filename so the chunk 1 is written in  `Final_LAS.las` and the second chunk is written in the same file which is erased.

If I'm correct the following code snippet should display two chunks

```r
opt_chunk_buffer(LAS_List ) = 0
opt_chunk_size(LAS_List ) = 10000
plot(LAS_list, chunk = TRUE)
```

Then you can fix it with `opt_chunk_alignment()`.

If I'm wrong you must provide more information

Comment: Running `opt_chunk_alignment(LAS_list)` returns `[1] 0 0`, does this seem okay?

Comment: This is the default. Change it so it aligns differently. Use e.g `opt_chunk_alignment(LAS_list) =  c(0, 3000)`to see how it affects the chunk pattern. It should shift the chunks by y = 3000

Answer (score 0):

This solution should also work. Each file in the LASCatalog is processed individually and saved accordingly. The file name template `{*}_{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}` gives each file a unique name and will not be overwritten. You can then calculate a DEM or something similar.

```
path = "C:/folder/.../"
ctg = readLAScatalog(path, progress = TRUE)

opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) = 0
opt_chunk_size(ctg) = 500
opt_output_files(ctg) = paste0(path, "{*}_{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}")

dtm = rasterize_terrain(ctg, 1, tin())
```